# What will happen if I put project1's SECRET_KEY to project2

Tags: python, django

Sorry to bother you guys but I have a question about Django's SECRET_KEY.

So I know these SECRET_KEY's are unique for every project.

So I think what will happen if I change this SCECRET_KEY.

Suppose I have created project1 and copied SECRET_KEY then paste it to project2's SECRET_KEY and after that I deleted project1.

So what will happen? I searched a lot but I didn't get any clear answer about it.

Thanks!!!

Comment: The secret key is used to sign secure cookies and things like that. Sharing a secret key means another app can decode such data. Which may or may not be in your interest.

Comment: Ok, but project1 is newly created and in project1 there isn't performed any task. I have just created it and copied the SECRET_KEY and just deleted it. In this case, there are any issues.

Comment: If the project was not even run in production and essentially nothing has happened, then no, basically nothing has happened. Just the act of copy and pasting the key does nothing, you're just copying some random string, and that's all that it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User experience directly impacted by a change of value are: sessions, the data decode will break, that is valid for any session backend (cookies, database, file-based or cache). The password reset token already sent won't work, users will have to ask for a new one.

Same will happen for both projects.

Key is used in various things, mainly used in session cookies.
CSRF key will probably change too.

Many things will be affected that use the SECRET_KEY

You can read more here - https://docs.gitguardian.com/secrets-detection/detectors/specifics/django_secret_key